# Abstract class error in android

Tags: java, android

I took this source file from https://github.com/Xlythe/Calculator/tree/lollipop/FloatingView 
and implemented in my app.

I got some errors with 'abstract' functions in that.

I changed

`public abstract class FloatingView extends Service`

to

`public class FloatingView extends Service`

and I got the following errors on functions

`protected abstract View inflateButton();
protected abstract View inflateView();`

Comment: If you have `abstract` methods, you should've implement them in your extended class. If you do remove the `abstract` key word from the class definition, you  have to implement them in the class itself.

Answer (score 1):

You deleted `abstract` declaration of `FloatingView`,means it won't be an abstract class,so no abstract method can exist in its methods.

you must delete the abstract of the two methods and implements the two methods.

```
protected View inflateButton(){//your code}
protectd View inflateView(){//your code}
```